# How to plot two rasters with different extensions

Tags: r, plot, mapping, raster

I am trying to plot two rasters with different extensions (from two different areas) and they are getting superimposed.

First raster `TN`:

> class: RasterLayer
>
> dimensions  : 1785, 2363, 4217955  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>
> resolution  : 0.11766, 0.11766  (x, y)
>
> extent      : 474953.5, 475231.5, 6539165, 6539375  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>
> coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=58 +lat_2=59.33333333333335 +lat_0=57.51755393055556 +lon_0=24 +x_0=500000 +y_0=6375000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs
>
> data source : C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSYhw1w\raster\r_tmp_2018-11-29_153551_4484_16660.grd
>
> names       : layer
>
> values      : 1, 3  (min, max)

Second raster `TS`:

> class       : RasterLayer
>
> dimensions  : 7266, 5237, 38052042  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>
> resolution  : 0.1141, 0.1141  (x, y)
>
> extent      : 474817, 475414.5, 6537431, 6538260  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>
> coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=58 +lat_2=59.33333333333335 +lat_0=57.51755393055556 +lon_0=24 +x_0=500000 +y_0=6375000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs
>
> data source : C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSYhw1w\raster\r_tmp_2018-11-29_154600_4484_99649.grd
>
> names       : layer
>
> values      : 1, 2  (min, max)

```
library(raster)
ext1 <- extent(6600000, 7000000, 66000000, 70000000) #total area extent

extent(TN) <- ext1
extent(TS) <- ext1 #rasters with the same extent (total area)

em = merge(extent(TN),extent(TS))
plot(em, type="n")
plot(TN,add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
plot(TS, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE)
```

[maps superimposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxe5W.png)

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem and exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I what to plot 2 different areas in a bigger area. But these 2 areas are not continuous, so they should be separated, not overlapped in the final map.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using `add=TRUE` for `TS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plots are overlapping just because you have the same extents for each raster. Give them different extents. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
logo <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
logo1 <- logo
logo2 <- logo
```

Assign the correct extents and merge:

```
ext1 <- extent(0, 45, 0, 45)
ext2 <- extent(55, 100, 55, 100)
extent(logo1) <- ext1
extent(logo2) <- ext2
em <- merge(ext1, ext2)
```

Add the data to a plot:

```
plot(em, type = "n")
plot(logo1, add = T, legend = F)
plot(logo2, add = T, legend = F)
```

[image: non-overlapping rasters]